# how to search in multi-dimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I print the array that `$_GET['paxID']` is equal to the array ID (I had **)

if `$_GET['paxID']` is 42 than it should print the second array

Following is my code:

```
Array
(
    **[13]** => Array
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => TEST1 TESTD
                )

            [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => MR
                )

        )

    **[42]** => Array
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => TEST2 TESTE
                )

            [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => MR
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: If what you printed is `$array`, the solution is `$array[$_GET['paxID']]`. If it isn't that simple, we need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate `$_GET['paxID']` and then you can access the element in the array by simply calling:

```
$yourArray[$_GET['paxID']]
```

Just remember to validate and filter `$_GET['paxID']` and to check if the key exists in the array.